# How do I return a collection from $q.defer().promise in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-factory

Angular v.1.6.1

I am attempting to return a collection using $q.defer().promise, but I am only getting a single record instead of both records that are returned from my service.

The Model:

```
angular.module('app').factory('User',
function() {

    /**
     * Constructor, with class name
     */
    function User(id, firstName, lastName, startDate) {
        // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }


    /**
     * Public method, assigned to prototype
     */
    User.prototype.getFullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    };

    User.apiResponseTransformer = function (responseData) {
        if (angular.isArray(responseData)) {
            return responseData
                .map(User.build)
                .filter(Boolean);
        }
        return User.build(responseData);
    }

    /**
     * Static method, assigned to class
     * Instance ('this') is not available in static context
     */
    User.build = function(data) {
        return new User(
            data.Id,
            data.FirstName,
            data.LastName,
            data.StartDate
        );
    };


    /**
     * Return the constructor function
     */
    return User;
});
```

The Service

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'userService';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', '$http', 'config', 'User', userService]);

function userService(common, $http, config, User) {
    var $q = common.$q;
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var service = {
        getUsers: getUsers,
        getUser: getUser
    };

    return service;

    function getUser(id) {
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: config.remoteServiceName + 'users/' + id
        }).then(function (response) {
            defer.resolve(User.apiResponseTransformer(response.data));
        }).then(function (response) {
            defer.reject(response);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

    function getUsers(startDate) {
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: config.remoteServiceName +'users/',
            params: {
                startDate: startDate
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            var users = [];
            angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {             
                users.push(User.apiResponseTransformer(value));
            });
            defer.resolve(users);
        }).then(function(response) {
            defer.reject(response);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }  
}
})();
```

The View Methods

```
function getUser() {
        userService.getUser(1).then(function successCallback(data) {
            vm.user = data;
        }).catch(function () {
            log('An error occured trying to get user...');
        });
    }

    function getUsers() {
        userService.getUsers(new Date().toUTCString()).then(function successCallback(data) {
            vm.users = data;
        }).catch(function () {
            log('An error occured trying to get user...');
        });
    }
```

Inside the view, the getUser call functions as expteced but getUsers receives only the first item in the collection from the service.  I have verified that response.data does contain the entire collection of objects and those objects are pushed into the users array.

Even calling defer.resolve(response.data) only sends the first item in the collection.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Check users collection before you call `defer.resolve(users)`.

Comment: Have you tried putting "var defer = $q.defer();" inside the functions instead of a global service variable ?

Comment: $q.defer objects only resolve once. Subsequent calls to the `.resolve` method are ignored. That's the way they work. They don't collect multiple resolves. Use $q.all to consolidate multiple promises.

Comment: Interesting, and @georgeawg is correct... the first defer that got called is the only result that was being returned from the service.  When I commented out the getUser call getUsers started returning the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` from a promise-based API. (If the object has a `.then` method, it is a promise.)

> ```
> //ERRONEOUS
> function getUser(id) {
>       $http({
>          method: 'get',
>          url: config.remoteServiceName + 'users/' + id
>       }).then(function (response) {
>          defer.resolve(User.apiResponseTransformer(response.data));
>       }).then(function (response) {
>          defer.reject(response);
>       });
>
>       return defer.promise;
> }
> ```

Since the invoking `$http(config)` can be chained with a `.then` method, it is a returning a promise. Any API call that can be chained with a `.then` method is a promise-based API. By paying attention to this detail, one can determine the nature of an unknown API.

```
//CORRECT
function getUser(id) {
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: config.remoteServiceName + 'users/' + id
    })

    var nextPromise = promise.then(function (response) {
        var value = User.apiResponseTransformer(response.data);
        //RETURN value to chain
        return value;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        //THROW to chain rejection
        throw errorResponse;
    });

    return nextPromise;
};
```

The chain has been broken into its part for clarity. The $http service call returns a promise. The `.then` method call returns a new promise that resolves to the value returned to its response handler. The new promise is then returned to the enclosing function.

It is important that there be a return (or throw) statement at every level of nesting.

#### Usage

```
getUser(id).then(function(transformedValue) {
    console.log(transformedValue);
});
```

*Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.*

*It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.*

*[--AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)*

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and example.  Very much appreciated!